# How to set dependencies for custom script in Azure scale sets?

Tags: azure

Here is the part of the template code. Now the scripts are executed in parallel. How to add the CustomScriptForLinux dependency from DockerExtension, what would first work for DockerExtension, and then CustomScriptForLinux?

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
      "name": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "VMScaleSet"
      },    
"extensionProfile": {
            "extensions": [
            {
                "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
                "name": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'DockerExtension')]",
                    "location": "[variables('location')]",
                    "properties": {
                      "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
                      "type": "DockerExtension",
                      "typeHandlerVersion": "1.1",
                      "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                      "settings": {},
                      "protectedSettings": {}
                   }
            },
            {
                "name": "ConfigureNginx",
                "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
                "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                      "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('ConfigureNginxScriptFolder'), '/', variables('ConfigureNginxScriptFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
                        ],
                        "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh ', variables('ConfigureNginxScriptFileName'))]"
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a `dependsOn` property on the `extensions` so your main workarounds are:

1. Implement your custom logic in scripts to wait for each other, say script 2 waits when script 1 creates file named `script1.done`
2. Remove one of the extensions from this template and create another nested deployment in this same template, and deploy both extensions, make nested deployment depend on the VMSS deployment.
   The problem with this approach is you would have to upgrade all the VMs in the VMSS to the latest version.

Comment: You should only need to add custom logic to the custom script. For example it could check /var/logs/azure... and wait for a completion message from the Docker extension. There's an example (in this case waiting for a diagnostics extension to complete, here: https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/extension-sequencing-in-azure-vm-scale-sets/ )

Comment: basically what I've said, thanks for the link thou ;) @sendmarsh